# How to use metatags_quick to add no-cache meta tags in D7?

Tags: 7, caching, meta-tags

I'd like to add the following to the meta tags for a single page on my D7 site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921793/internet-explorer-6-and-higher-cache-and-temporary-files/)

However, when I try to use [metatags_quick](http://drupal.org/project/metatags_quick) to accomplish this, it names all my metatags as

```
<meta name="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no store, must revalidate">
```

with the "name=" attributes rather than "http-equiv".  How can add these tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to say that, in some cases, you can add by template way your meta tags to your specific page.

you can locate `html.php.tpl` in `modules > system` file. copy and paste it inside your template directory. then add your meta tags using some php code to show these tags only in that specific page:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_GET['q'])){
      $path = $_GET['q'];
      if(preg_match('/test/', $path)){
      ?>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
      <?  
      } 
  };
  ?>
```

(you can add this snippet before, for example, the `<title>` tag line)

remember that if you need your meta in more pages, you can replace the pattern of [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) php function (in this example is `/test/`) for several pages (for example `/(test|another_test_page|another)/` )

**Update**: if you do not see changes, is very important **clear cache** to see changes.

**Update2** [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/6) could be an useful function to get the current alias: Given an internal Drupal path, return the alias.

Comment: I copied this into the html.tpl.php (it's that way, right?  You wrote html.php.tpl) just above the <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title> line, and changed '/test/' to 'Page-Name', since I'm looking to do this on "www.mysite.com/Page-Name".  I moved this into my active template directory.  It did not seem to have any effect, and isn't visible when I view source on that page.  Any suggestions on what I've done wrong?

Comment: hello @Mittenchops. change Page-Name by /Page-Name/ (please do not remove // characters, are important delimiters of string, and not is related with paths). Also remember that you can debug each php line, for example, see with `echo $_GET['q'];` if is getting the correct string. also review if changing delimiters in preg_match() function help (change /Page-Name/ for #Page-Name#)

 one note: please remember do not change the html.php.tpl in `modules > system`. you must change a copy used inside your template directory.

Comment: That's really strange---I added the slashes back, and noticed that even when I add `if(true){ ... ` as the conditional statement, it still isn't displaying.  I am editing the copy in my theme's template directory, rather than in `modules > system`, so I wonder what the issue is.   The place I need to copy the file is in my theme's template directory, right?

Comment: I'm dumb---had to clear cache.  Your solution worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: you have reason, clear cache! I will add this in the answer! Thanks to you.